# Other than direct radiation, how can RF interference transfer between stacked PCBs?

Tags: electromagnetism, radio, microwave

I have VHF aviation radio consisting of 3 boards stacked upon each other: digital, receiver and transmitter, the digital is on ‘top’ with receiver in the middle, there is thick shielding between the transmitter and receiver.

The digital uses a reference TCXO at 30MHz, when the boards are laid next to each other on a butterfly board I get good sensitivity. When stacked the sensitivity drops

I’m seeing a lot of harmonics of 30MHz near the connector between digital and receiver, and on some other parts of the board including on some power tracks, however no problem when on the butterfly board. But these don’t seem to travel to the receiver directly on the connector since no problem on the butterfly board. I’ve not found any surface track loops so far, and shielding different areas of the digital doesn’t seem to do anything

When I filter my signal generator to remove its own harmonics the problem goes, seems like mixing of these and the 30MHz harmonics down to my IF or RF and blocking, and these harmonics must be getting to the receiver

BUT since  shielding different parts of the digital and the connector has no effect and connecting the boards side by side stops the problem...I’m stumped. I have the problem of reducing the harmonic levels but I first need to find out how they are getting onto the receiver. Removing the standoffs between the digital and receiver has no effect,
Using a case on or around the digital and receiver doesn’t effect it

Comment: Coupling on power and control signals is often something you need to take specific measures to prevent.

Comment: The coupling doesn’t seem to be via conduction and I’ve tried shielding. I’ve applied the standard decoupling caps and ferrite beads on all sensitive lines

Comment: How are you shielding the boards?  
What is on the butterfly board, and how far apart are they?  
Any inductors on the RF board near the TCXO?   
How about power supply decoupling?   
Why do you have a TCXO on a digital board?   
Is the TCXO output coming over to the RF board? How clean is it? You might have a couple of different interference paths that are combining.  
The Sensitivity drops? Does that hold across the band?  What frequency are you measuring sensitivity? if it's not n* 30 MHz, you may be chasing the wrong thing.

Comment: Either your shielding is not effective (not properly grounded or has openings) or the noise is be being conducted by power or signals.

Comment: I've been shielding using a can (about 2x6cm) which is grounded via a wire, i'm holding this over difference areas, I know this isn't ideal but I would still expect to see some difference 

Maybe the connector is providing a path for radiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric fields will couple everywhere, everywhere water can flow. If there are holes, even if not line-of-sight, the electric flux will enter and upset the nodes behind the shield.

The coupling of electric fields, ABOVE A PLANE, drops off as the CUBE of the distance. (thanks to Howard Johnson for writing of this) Thus Efield coupling through the **air**, in the butterfly setup with the spurs adequately low, becomes unacceptable and desenses when the 3 boards are all folded up.

==============================================

Do you count Efield (such as parallel-plate or wire-wire or wire-plate) coupling as "direct radiation"?

This is all near-field, where the E and H modes are accurately modeled **separately**.

Thus if radiation of any form is not the path, you are left with wires.

But since "closeness" seems the cause, then Efields or Hfields may be the culprit.

Can you make sketches of where these are possible?
and can you identify the signal injection levels (such as -140 or -120 dBm) that cause desense?

Comment: The PCB layout seems to forming a bucket handle shaped path that goes around the board, pass the connector and the reference oscillator. I think the harmonics are getting onto this path and then the connector and onto the 12v on the receiver which goes straight to the receiver front end to bias PIN diodes used for tuning.

The problem was reduced to the point of passing by softening the transition gradient of the reference oscillator clock's output buffer, this reduces the harmonic energy by reducing the energy needed at the higher harmonics to produce the clock transitions.